# Installing Debian 8.9 on HP EliteBook 840 G4 laptop

Tags: linux, laptop, debian

I would like to install Debian 8.9 (Jessie) on a HP EliteBook 840 G4 laptop. `lspci` (when executed from a shell launched from inside Debian Installer) informs me that it possesses the following Ethernet device:

```
Ethernet Controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)
```

The laptop is plugged into Ethernet, and a WLAN network would be available as well.

Early on during Debian installation (at step "Detect network hardware") I run into the following problem: The installer informs me that no Ethernet card was detected and that a driver is needed for my Ethernet card. It then presents me with a long list of choices, but among them is no obvious match to `Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)`.

I've tried the installation process by booting both from the `debian-8.9.0-amd64-netinst.iso` and `firmware-8.9.0-amd64-netinst.iso` netinst images, but ran into the same problem each time.

So what is needed in order to install Debian 8.9 on that particular laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Switching to Debian 9.2 (Stretch), which was possible in my situation, allowed me to overcome the problem.

After starting the installation by booting from `firmware-9.2.1-amd64-netinst.iso` (on a 1st USB stick) I received the following message:

```
Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate. The firmware can be loaded from removable media, such
as a USB stick or floppy.

The missing firmware files are iwlwifi-8265-26.ucode, iwlwifi-8265-26.ucode iwlwifi-8265-24.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-23.ucode

If you have such media available now, insert it, and continue.
```

After then inserting [`firmware-iwlwifi_20161130-3_all.deb`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-iwlwifi) (on a 2nd USB stick), the installation was able to recognize both the Ethernet and WLAN network interfaces:

```
enp0s31f6: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
wlp2sn: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (wireless)
```

Starting the installation by booting from `debian-9.2.1-amd64-netinst.iso` resulted in the same message, but here the installer apparently was not able to load the missing firmware files form the 2nd US stick.